# Access $parent from ViewModel

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

*This code is just a generic example of what I'd like to accomplish*

Parent View Model

```
var customerViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.Images = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.NotifyUser = function(){
        alert('Success');
    };
};
```

Child View Model

```
var imageViewModel = function(item){
    var self = this;

    self.Rename = function(filePath){
        self.src(filePath);
        $parent.NotifyUser();
    };
};
```

How can I make `$parent.NotifyUser();` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push a new child, pass the parent view model into the child's view model.

```
var customerViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.Images = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.NotifyUser = function(){
        alert('Success');
    };

    self.Images.push(new imageViewModel({foo:'bar'}, self));
};

var imageViewModel = function(item, $parent){
    var self = this;

    self.Rename = function(filePath){
        self.src(filePath);
        $parent.NotifyUser();
    };
};
```